# Android studio instalando o aplicativo por cima de outro aplicativo

Tags: android, android-studio

Estive utilizando o mesmo apk para aperfeiçoa-lo, fui na pasta e dei um ctrl v ctrl c e comecei a editar o novo apk. Mudei o nome, o nome das pastas, mudei algumas telas, só que quando vou emular no celular ele instala por cima do que eu ja tinha feito.

Como corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que identifica o App é seu `applicationId`:

Em seu **build.gradle** :

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.pacote.exemplo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
```

Altere o `applicationId` para que gere outro app.

Comment: Deu certo Thiago, obgdo